# Alternatives to Select-String

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for an alternative to `Select-String` to use within my function. At present, everything else in the function returns the data I need except this command:

```
Get-Content "$((Get-Location).Drive.Name):\Test\file.log" | Select-Object -Last 100 | Select-String -Pattern "SCHEDULEREC STATUS BEGIN" -Context 0,24
```

On it's own the command works fine, albeit slowly. This is due in part to the fact that the file it reads using Get-Content is sometimes 4MB to 700MB in size. However, I also found that even if I manage to cut the unnecessary information out of the file and reduce it down to only (for example) 5KB, when used in the function the `Select-String` will only get the "SCHEDULEREC STATUS BEGIN" headline and not collect the rest of the lines to 24 despite working fine separately (also the rest of the commands following this one in the function still work fine regardless).

The environment consists of Windows Server 2003 to 2019, using Powershell v1+, as such any commands used would need to work across all versions of Powershell. The function's purpose is to gather TSM (Tivoli Storage Manager) information, without the environment it may be difficult to reproduce the issue I'm encountering.

---

Full function:

```
function Start-WindowsTSMBackup {
    <#
        .Synopsis
            Standard backup process for TSM based clients on Windows

        .Description
            This script helps in going through the required tasks of initial troubleshooting remotely on a remote computer.

        .Parameter ComputerName
            Server name for which you want to run the TSM process on; you will be prompted to input

        .Parameter Output
            Change the location of "$Output" to where you want the success/failure texts to go

        .Parameter Credential
            Allows usage over domain/local networks that require password authentication

        .Notes
            NAME: Start-WindowsTSMBackup.ps1
            AUTHOR: mm079

    #>

    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [ValidateScript({Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1})]
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] # Will request the input of the computername
        [string]$ComputerName,

        # Output directory for the results
        [string]$Output = "C:\Temp\$ComputerName Results.txt",

        <#
        # Use this to submit credentials automatically
        [string]$Username = "domain\username",
        [string]$Password = "Pa$$w0rd",
        [securestring]$SecurePassword = ( $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force),
        [pscredential]$Credential = (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$SecurePassword),
        #>

        # Use this to submit credentials by requested input
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential = (Get-Credential)
    ) # Param

    BEGIN {

    } # BEGIN

    PROCESS {

        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {

            if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0) {
                try {
                    $Results = invoke-command -script {

                        #Obtain verbose information for testing
                        VerbosePreference = "continue"

                        #Query the server for basic information - Hostname and Current time
                        Write-Output $env:COMPUTERNAME
                        Write-Output ('Current Data/Time: ' + (Get-Date) )

                        # Retrieve the last boot time
                        SystemInfo | find /i "Boot Time"

                        # TSM Service Last Restart Time
                        Write-Output ('TSM Service Last Restart Time: ' + (Get-EventLog -LogName "System" -Source "Service Control Manager" -EntryType "Information" -Message "*TSM Scheduler Service*running*" -Newest 1).TimeGenerated )
                        Write-Verbose "Basic Information processed"
                       

                            if (Test-Path "$((Get-Location).Drive.Name):\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient") {

                                # Obtains DSMSched information
                                Get-Content "$((Get-Location).Drive.Name):\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient\dsmsched.log" | Select-Object -Last 100 | Select-String -Pattern "SCHEDULEREC STATUS BEGIN" -Context 0,24
                                Write-Verbose "DSMSched Information processed"

                                # Obtains DSMErrors
                                Get-Content "$((Get-Location).Drive.Name):\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient\dsmerror.log" | Select-Object -Last 200 | Select-String -Pattern "Error", "failure"
                                Write-Verbose "DSMError Information processed"

                            } # if
                            else {

                              Write-Output "File path to TSM logs not found"
                              Write-Verbose "Unable to process TSM information due to invalid path - not found"
                            } # else

                            ## Restart the "TSM Scheduler Service"
                            if (Get-Service -Name "TSM*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
                            {
                                Stop-Service -Name "TSM*" -PassThru
                                Start-Service -Name "TSM*" -PassThru
                                Write-Verbose "TSM Service processed"
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                Write-Output "Could not restart TSM Service"
                                Write-Verbose "TSM Service restart failed"
                            }

                    } # invoke-command
                    -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop
                } # try
                catch {
                    
                    Write-Error "$($_.Exception.Message) - Line Number: $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)"

                } # catch
            } # if

        } # foreach



    } # PROCESS
    END {

    } # END


} # Function Start-WindowsTSMBackup
```

---

### Expected output

```
EXAMPLESERVERNAME
Current Data/Time: 02/02/2021 14:27:00
System Boot Time: 01/15/2021 12:00:00 AM
TSM Service Last Restart Time: 02/01/2021 16:27:21

02/01/2021 21:00:00 --- SCHEDULEREC STATUS BEGIN
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of objects inspected: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of objects backed up: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of objects updated: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of objects rebound: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of objects deleted: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of objects expired: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of objects failed: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of objects encrypted: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of subfile objects: #### 
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of objects grew: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of retries: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of bytes inspected: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total number of bytes transferred: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Data transfer time: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Network data transfer rate: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Aggregate data transfer rate: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Objects compressed by: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Total data reduction ratio: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Subfile objects reduced by: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Elapsed processing time: ####
02/01/2021 21:00:00 --- SCHEDULEREC STATUS END
02/01/2021 21:00:00 --- SCHEDULEREC OBJECT END BACKUP 02/01/2021 21:00:00
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Scheduled event 'BACKUP' completed successfully.
02/01/2021 21:00:00 Sending results for scheduled event 'BACKUP'

02/01/2021 21:00:00 AAABBBCCC Error processing '\\SERVER\DRIVELETTER\PATH\PROCESS' the object is in use by another process
02/01/2021 21:00:00 AAABBBCCC Error processing '\\SERVER\DRIVELETTER\PATH\File.txt' the object is in use by another process
02/01/2021 21:00:00 AAABBBCCC Incremental backup of '\\SERVER\DRIVEPATH\ finished with 2 error(s)

Status: Stopped
Name: TSM Scheduler Service
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER

Status: Stopped
Name: TSM Scheduler Service for SERVER
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER

Status: Running
Name: TSM Scheduler Service
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER

Status: Running
Name: TSM Scheduler Service for SERVER
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER
```

---

### Current output #1

```
EXAMPLESERVERNAME
Current Data/Time: 02/02/2021 14:27:00
System Boot Time: 01/15/2021 12:00:00 AM
TSM Service Last Restart Time: 02/01/2021 16:27:21

02/01/2021 21:00:00 --- SCHEDULEREC STATUS BEGIN
02/01/2021 21:00:00 AAABBBCCC Error processing '\\SERVER\DRIVELETTER\PATH\PROCESS' the object is in use by another process
02/01/2021 21:00:00 AAABBBCCC Error processing '\\SERVER\DRIVELETTER\PATH\File.txt' the object is in use by another process
02/01/2021 21:00:00 AAABBBCCC Incremental backup of '\\SERVER\DRIVEPATH\ finished with 2 error(s)

Status: Stopped
Name: TSM Scheduler Service
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER

Status: Stopped
Name: TSM Scheduler Service for SERVER
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER

Status: Running
Name: TSM Scheduler Service
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER

Status: Running
Name: TSM Scheduler Service for SERVER
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER
```

---

### Current output #2

```
EXAMPLESERVERNAME
Current Data/Time: 02/02/2021 14:27:00
System Boot Time: 01/15/2021 12:00:00 AM
TSM Service Last Restart Time: 02/01/2021 16:27:21


02/01/2021 21:00:00 AAABBBCCC Error processing '\\SERVER\DRIVELETTER\PATH\PROCESS' the object is in use by another process
02/01/2021 21:00:00 AAABBBCCC Error processing '\\SERVER\DRIVELETTER\PATH\File.txt' the object is in use by another process
02/01/2021 21:00:00 AAABBBCCC Incremental backup of '\\SERVER\DRIVEPATH\ finished with 2 error(s)

Status: Stopped
Name: TSM Scheduler Service
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER

Status: Stopped
Name: TSM Scheduler Service for SERVER
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER

Status: Running
Name: TSM Scheduler Service
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER

Status: Running
Name: TSM Scheduler Service for SERVER
DisplayName: TSM Scheduler Service
PSComputerName: SERVER
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What does this have to do with `Get-Content`? The function already returns each line. If you wanted to read the last 100 lines, `Get-Content -Tail 100`. The current script is slow because it loads everything in memory before  filtering out everything but the 100 last lines. As for `Select-String` are you sure `DATA` doesn't appear in the last line? You asked for the 24 lines *after* `DATA`

Comment: Post a reproducible example that demonstrates the problem - actual data contents, expected result and actual result. What you ask is what `Get-Content` already does. The problem seems to be with `Select-String` only and could easily be because the data just isn't there

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos
Unfortunately "Get-Content -Tail 100" won't work for me as the servers I have this running on run Powershell v1 not v3.

Regarding the Select-String, the code works as intended when used stand-alone. If I go to any of the servers and input the code, it will return the 24 lines I am requesting with line 0 being "DATA" regardless of the file size.

The Select-String does not work as expect though once added into the larger function though unless the file size is smaller than 50kb, and even then it only shows line 0, "DATA".

Comment: If you want to get any answer, put all the relevant information in the question, especially if you use unsupported OS and Powershell versions. PS 1.0 is *way too old* and no supported OS comes with it. There's still no example of the data, no problem description, no way to reproduce the problem. And the actual problem doesn't seem to have *anything* to do with `Get-Content`. It's `Select-String` that selects the lines, not `Get-Content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not have a true solution to the issue, instead a re-work was done to the entire code and then implemented within BladeLogic to make it work as needed. As such an answer to this is no longer needed. Thank you to those who attempted to assist.